# Is there a good way to add Equinox source to Eclipse to help debugging an OSGi bundle?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, equinox

I am banging my head against a mess of JNI code and DLLs that we are trying to shoehorn into an OSGi bundle.  It has been particularly hard to get good debugging info out of the system and I have spent too much time stepping through raw byte code trying to infer what is happening inside equinox--when I really don't care--I am just not getting useful errors out.  It would be great if I could have easy access to the equinox source in the debugger to see why and where it was loading what.

The simple answer of downloading all the source and building my own Eclipse would be one solution, but it feels very heavy handed.  Is there a "grab source" repo I could go to and install from or some such thing?

It just feels like there should be an easier way to go about this.  Something akin to using the debug libraries or installing the SRPM in another situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse ships with source by default, look for *.source in the plugins folder, it could be you just need to set up the source path in the debugger.

If you actually don't have the source, getting it will depend a little on what version of eclipse you are running.  For Galileo or Helios you can try going to Help -> Install New Software.  Work with the Galileo (or Helios) repository.  Uncheck "Group items by category", in the filter type "source".  In particular, most of the equinox source will be in "Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources".

Alternatively you can also go to the [Equinox download page](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/) and get the [Equinox SDK](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-3.5.2-201002111343/download.php?dropFile=equinox-SDK-3.5.2.zip) which has the source.

Comment: I see that the `.source*` files are present.  I'll see about adding them to the source path, although one would expect that to be part of the default configuration.